# Motivation of Monge-Ampere equation

Tags: mathematics-social-history, differential-equations

I have a question about Monge-Ampere equation.
I read a book *The shape of inner space* by Shing-Tung Yau.

Chapter 5 in this book, Complex-Monge-Ampere equation's explaination was so interesting. In the beginning, Monge researched this equation during french revolution. after a long time, Ampere researched the equation succeed to Monge.

> But there were still more preliminaries to be done before Cheng and I
> could attack complex Monge-Ampère equations. We started working on
> the Dirichlet problem, named after the German mathematician Lejeune
> Dirichlet. It’s what we call a boundary value problem, and tackling
> such problems is usually the first thing we do when trying to solve
> an elliptic differential equation. We discussed an example of a
> boundary value problem in Chapter 3, the Plateau problem, which is
> often visualized in terms of soap films and which stated that for an
> arbitrary closed curve, one could find a minimal surface stretching
> across that same boundary. Every point on that surface is also a
> solution to a particular differential equation.
> (*The shape of inner space* p.113-114)

This is part of the book.  When I read this part, there are various terminologies such as Plateau problem, Dirichlet problem and so on. So I want to know about Monge-Ampere equation's historical and mathematical background for understanding '*flow of the idea*' above terminologies. So I searched Google about this.

According to my research, Monge-Ampere equation is a **non-linear generalization of the Poisson equation**. Is this right?

Comment: "appropriate source" what I wrote means "historical motivation and background" written by English.

Comment: you can edit your own question no need to add self-comments

Comment: Thank you for your advice!!